# Coolant in the oil

Tags: oil, coolant, dodge

I was topping off my oil and I accidentally splashed maybe an ounce of coolant instead, is this a huge deal or is a splash okay?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I think it is ok, but you change your oil just to be safe.

Comment: Buying and using a funnel may help avoid this in the future.